# Opening File AND Directories Using FileChooser only in JavaFX

Tags: file, javafx, directory, filechooser

Someone asked this question 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644861/javafx-filechooser-select-files-and-or-directories). The answer was, Linux systems didn't support that functionality natively, therefore it couldn't be supported across all of JavaFX.

Just for clarification, I'm looking for a way to give users the ability to select multiple files and directories at once using only FileChooser, not DirectoryChooser. I have the system working now where I ask the user if they'd like to import music files or search folders for music files. Depending on their response, I open either FileChooser or DirectoryChooser. This however, is confusing for some users and it's more cumbersome than I'd like.

Does anyone know if this functionality is up and running yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way using javafx from what I know. But you could go for the awt FileChooser. It doesnt look remotly like a native FileChooser, but at least it gets the job done. (Ps. Layout can always be altered)

Comment: Yes I've been considering that and JFileChooser. Looking nice is unfortunately important so either option is less than perfect. Thanks for the suggestion